# java - copy plugin to eclipse dropins folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am still learning eclipse pde.

I want to copy plugin to C:eclipse/dropins folder.
I am able to do this by hardcoding the destination path.
However, I want to get this path progammatically.

How do I get the path of my eclipse/dropins folder in Java.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will have an environment variable for dropins, but there should be an environment variable %ECLIPSE_HOME% under which dropins could be found.
So you could access it as:

```
String eclipseHome = System.getenv( ECLIPSE_HOME )
String dropinsPath = eclipseHome + File.separator + "dropins";
```